# How to pause work ETA notifications from Google Asssitant?

Tags: google-assistant

Every day Google gives me a notification which gives me time to get to work and the best route to take. It also tells me the best way to get to work in my daily briefing through Google Assistant.

Currently, I'm on holiday so I don't need these notifications. Is there a way of creating a holiday time so that the notifications will resume automatically after it.

I know I can stop the notifications, but is there a way of just pausing them for a certain amount of time?

Android 8.1.0/Nokia 6